# Cache ZF2 Http Client request

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is it possible to cache an HTTP Client request of `ZF2`?

```
$client = new \Zend\Http\Client('http://example.com', array(
    'maxredirects' => 0,
    'timeout'      => 30
));
$response = $client->send();
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Avoid getting the contents from that external websites every time that the page is visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much cache every request no matter what framework you are using, I recommend reading a little bit about Proxy pattern, you could use memcached for instance and if its not present in memcached, you delegate it to the real service.

If you want to do it 100% with ZF2 You could take a look at the storage adapters:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html

Basically, when you get a response from the client, you can cache it with a given key, maybe the url or the ID of the resource you are fetching and store it in memcached or reddis or whatever you are using for caching.

Comment: is there nothing `\Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader::setCache($cache);` ? it's so clean...